# Dynamically create nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary of dictionaries. The values will be created dynamically and I'm curious if there is a better, more pythonic way, of doing the following:

```
#!python3

dict = {}
persons = ('jack', 'jill', 'fido', 'spot')
for person in persons:
  if person not in dict:
    dict[person] = {}
    dict[person]['count'] = 1
  else:
    dict[person]['count'] += 1
```

This is obviously pseudo-code only meant for learning :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself doing a lot of boilerplate code for setting up defaults, it's a good time to checkout [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

This will let you establish the default value for any new keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: {'count': 0})

persons = ('jack', 'jill', 'fido', 'spot', 'jack')

for person in persons:
    d[person]['count'] += 1
```

Alternatively, since you are counting the number of values in a list, it's worth looking at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This will do the counting for you automatically. So

```
from collections import Counter

Counter(persons)
# Counter({'jack': 2, 'jill': 1, 'fido': 1, 'spot': 1})
```

You can stick this in a dict comprehension if you need the sub-dictionaries:

```
d = {k: {'count':v} for k, v in Counter(persons).items()}
```

Resulting in

```
{'jack': {'count': 2},
 'jill': {'count': 1},
 'fido': {'count': 1},
 'spot': {'count': 1}}
```